# How to type special characters using keyboard module?

Tags: python, keyboard

I have a program which will detect when the keyboard presses a specified order of keys, and then replace it with something. How can I do this with special symbols?

```py
def replace():
    if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        if keyboard.is_pressed('i'):
            for x in range (1, 3):
                keyboard.press_and_release('Backspace')
            keyboard.typewrite( #special symbol goes here )
```

Comment: Can you not type an ALT code? (So for Windows something like `Alt-1, 2, 3, 4` and for Mac something like `Alt-K`)

Comment: No, I am not able to. I am using a laptop without the `alt` key.

Comment: That shouldn't matter (if your keyboard is physically missing the `alt` key). What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 OS, but i made a typo. I have the `alt` key, but not the `num lock` key.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I gave you an answer now that you have supplied me with enough info.

Answer (score 0):

Not having a num-lock key does not matter. Python is acting as a keyboard (separate from yours). We just need the scan code for the numpad numbers.

Let's type an Omega `Ω` char which is `alt + 2,3,4`. First we get the scan codes -

```
import keyboard    

print(keyboard.key_to_scan_codes('2'))
>> (3, 80)
print(keyboard.key_to_scan_codes('3'))
>> (4, 81)
print(keyboard.key_to_scan_codes('4'))
>> (5, 75)
```

The 2nd numbers are the scan codes for the numpad numbers. Knowing this, we can now make the code -

```
keyboard.press('alt')
keyboard.press_and_release(80)
keyboard.press_and_release(81)
keyboard.press_and_release(75)
keyboard.release('alt')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a couple of questions. First, how did you find the alt\scan codes? Second, this particular example doesn't work for me, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: My first code block shows how to find scan codes. Try `print(keyboard.key_to_scan_codes('2'))` and you will see the output. My 2nd code block is what actually creates the Omega char. If that is not working for you, make sure you are not hitting any key while it runs. If you want to be safe - import `time` and add a `time.sleep(1)` to the beginning. Also make sure you `import keyboard`. If this doesn't work, let me know your errors/output, and how you are launching the script.